# Escape \51 in javascript

Tags: javascript, special-characters

My issue is the following:
I have a field with a file path: `"\\random.ad.test.stuff.com\folder\level 1\51. level 2\ level 3"`

I want to create an array with this information

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "\\random.ad.test.stuff.com\folder\level 1\51. level 2\level 3";
    var array = str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "_");

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array;
}
```

Problem is that **\51** the character code for a right parenthesis. So the result is

> "_random_ad_test_stuff_comfolder_level 1__. level 2_level 3".

How can I escape the **\51** as well as insert a _after .com ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't escape the string after-the-fact. In a string literal, as you said, `\51` is `)`, exactly as though you'd typed `)` in the string literal; there is no difference in the resulting string:

```js
console.log("\51" === ")"); // true
```

You have to escape the characters in the literal:

```js
var str = "\\\\random.ad.test.stuff.com\\folder\\level 1\\51. level 2\\level 3";
// --------^-^-------------------------^-------^--------^------------^
console.log(str);
```

Note that this is just because you're using a string literal. If you *read* that string from somewhere, there's no need to escape it at all. Escaping (in this sense) is a *string literal* thing, not a string thing.

---

You've said this comes from an XML file, and asked what you have to do to the file to avoid this problem. The answer is: Nothing. Read in the XML file, and when you get those filenames from it, you'll get strings with the correct characters  again, escaping is for string *literals*, but XML isn't a string literal.

Example:

```js
// "Read" the file
var xmlText = document.querySelector("#xml").textContent;

// Parse it
var oParser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(xmlText, "application/xml");

// Use its contents; the information you'll get will be valid strings,
// no escaping needed
var entries = oDOM.querySelectorAll("entry");
console.log(entries[0].getAttribute("attr"));
console.log(entries[1].firstChild.nodeValue);
```

```html
<script id="xml" type="text/xml"><root>
<entry attr="\\random.ad.test.stuff.com\folder\level 1\51. level 2\level 3" />
<entry>\\random.ad.test.stuff.com\folder\level 1\51. level 2\level 3</entry>
</root></script>
```

In that example, I've shown taking the string from an attribute, or from the body of an element, the two usual ways you put information in XML.

Comment: Okay, so this information comes from an XML file. Ideally I would then do something to that file to escape those  characters I presume?

Comment: @Onnie - There shouldn't be any need to. Read in the XML and you'll get a string (not a string literal). I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: Have no clue where it went wrong initially, but it niw works. Thanks!